# Настройка параметров структуры Excel при помощи xlsxwriter

Tags: python, excel

Есть таблица сгруппированная при помощи **xlsxwriter**, в которой из-за большого кол-ва строк, чтобы свернуть группу, приходится скролить документ.

---

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

###### *Как с помощью **xlsxwriter** поместить кнопку свернуть/развернуть в первую строку группы?*

Желаемый результат:

---

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Добавьте, пожалуйста, в вопрос минимальный пример кода, как это  у вас получилось.

Comment: Строки группировал с помощью данной команды:
worksheet.set_row(row, None, None, {'level': 1})
Однако, в аргументах функции set_row не нашел подходящего параметра для решения проблемы

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Решение было найдено на английской версии stackoverflow:
In XlsxWriter you can control this via the worksheet `outline_settings()` method. In particular set the `symbols_below` parameter to false.